# How to show time stamp for send/receive messages for a chat app?

Tags: android, timestamp, chat

I have developed a chat app using GCM service provided by Google for android.
I have a problem of showing time stamp of sent/received messages to the user.

What I can do is use the device time for sent messages so that user see the same time i.e of device in the chat app, but for the messages that are received,

1. if the device 2 has time out of sync with global time then the time sent by it will be of no use.
2. even there will be problem of time zone.

Comment: You will know the timezone, you can easily convert everything using the Java Calendar class. Just convert and store everything as UTC or epoch time (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)

Comment: Sync time via your own webservice or some Internet time service: (http://www.nist.gov/pml/div688/grp40/its.cfm)

Comment: ohk, but how about the device 2 has time out of sync. then 

it might show

me: "text"  6.30pm
device 2: "text" 6.20 pm
me: "text" 6.31pm